# Can photos be printed on the actual disks in magnetic hard drive the same way they are put on CDs

Tags: hard-drive

I've been reading about the [Event Horizon Telescope](http://www.eventhorizontelescope.org/technology/index.html) and found the Computer World article [Massive telescope array aims for black hole, gets gusher of data](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2972251/space-technology/massive-telescope-array-aims-for-black-hole-gets-gusher-of-data.html). In it they describe what must be the world's biggest Sneaker Net.

What caught my eye was this image of a hard drive with the cover open.

It looks like a photograph of ice cubes is printed on to the magnetic disk, but that just doesn't make sense to me. The media needs to be extremely smooth, clean, and well balanced. I can't imagine they are run through some kind of color printer, and then (in this application) sealed in Helium with photos of ice cubes.

But it's probably 10 years since I've seen the inside of a hard drive, so...

Is this just a silly photoshopped image, or does this happen?

Looking for a factual answer here, not just opinion or best guess.

**below:** "[HGST's He10 10TB hard drive seals in helium and user shingled magnetic recording to pack 10TB of capacity into a 3.5-in form factor](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2972251/space-technology/massive-telescope-array-aims-for-black-hole-gets-gusher-of-data.html)."

[image]

Comment: The ice is needed to keep it running cool.

Comment: Definitely photoshopped. You might do better asking the graphic design or photography SE- there are probably some telltale signs in the edges and shadows around the bottom circumference.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany that's what I thought at first too, but then I considered that these guys are trying to image a black hole in the center of the galaxy, maybe they can also put a photo on a hard drive literally. I zoomed in and I do see some detail in the shadow that suggests they are - at least - very good at using photoshop.

Comment: There's the CD technology Lightscribe: http://www.cdrom2go.com/introducing-lightscribe-technology-dec-27-2005.aspx - but that's for the non-data side.

Comment: @uhoh I know a guy who could do this on his Mac in about 30 seconds (mostly getting the mask just right).  Amazing how proficient some people are with software tools.

Comment: @pjc50 Actually it is marking on the data side of a CD/DVD (on the ink cover). But this is a [hard drive platter](https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/hdd-platter-21591117.jpg) which looks like a mirror .

Comment: @OlinLathrop is right - it [is for cooling](http://www.techspot.com/news/58010-hgst-becomes-first-to-introduce-10tb-hard-drive-in-35-form-factor.html)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question has nothing to do with electronics design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This is a Photoshopped marketing image -- real hard disk platters are metallic and highly reflective, with no markings. The image might be from a press release describing how these disks can be used for "cold storage", for instance. :)

[image]

Unlike writable CDs, recording data on a hard disk doesn't change its appearance, and there's no reason why a hard disk platter would be decorated this way. (Opening one of the drives described would destroy it by releasing the helium, after all, so there's no reason anyone outside the factory would ever see it!)

Comment: Losing the helium atmosphere would probably be much less of an issue compared to any dust that you let in while doing that (unless you've got a clean room handy).

Comment: @DanMašek My understanding is that the helium atmosphere is essential to keep the head at the right height. Normal hard disks can often run in room air for a few minutes until some dust gets in the wrong spot, but a helium-filled drive will probably crash as soon as you power it on.

Comment: In one of the articles I've seen "which hermetically seals in helium in order to reduce internal drive friction and power use". As I understand it, the hermetic seal has a useful side effect of making the drive insensitive to the low ambient pressure at the observatory site. Either way, I fully agree that printing on the platters would be utterly pointless.

Comment: I think the disks are not made of metal, but possibly glass. They look shiny because you can see tbe metal coating through the glass. (See @Tony's answer beliw)  And how can you tell if it's photoshopped, or just printed on a disk for show - that wouldn't actually be used in a functioning drive?

Comment: I did some searching and only found this one ice image, which suggests it was difficult or expensive to do - thus printed, and possibly shown at trade shows. If it was photoshopped, they would have made all kinds of patterns since it only takes "30 seconds".

Comment: @uhoh By "metallic", I meant in appearance. You're right that most platters are made of glass, but they've got some sort of exotic coating on them (on both sides), so you aren't seeing anything "through" the glass -- all you see is the coating.

Comment: @uhoh As far as the image goes, I certainly can't prove that they didn't make one that looked like that, but if they did (which seems unlikely, it's harder than Photoshoppping an image), it would have been 100% for show. Any layer of ink on top of the recording media would make the disk unusable.

Answer (score 2):

There are [many ways](http://www.canvasfactory.com/ca/photos-on-glass/) to print photo's on glass with acrylic ink, even if it is sputtered with magnetic particles.

https://epson.com/direct-cd-dvd-printing
The most common fault of users and OEM's is they put on unbalanced layers of ink and it causes the CD to vibrate and lose tracking and fails in some CD DVD players.

Side info.

I think it may be a silicon crystal enlarged in the photo made to give the illusion of ice.

There is a lot more to HDD's than marketing will ever tell you. (having been in the HDD manufacturing side for over 10 yrs)   This product is not on the market yet.

Helium has many properties that may reduce faults, but also some risks, like seal leakage through thin plastic coating. But I imagine it prevents condensation after cool shipping and rapid unpacking in a warmer room since air (N2, H2 & O2  etc) is replaced with He. So that's a bonus. The gas density is lighter, so it flies lower or could be run at faster RPM's during servo-writing.

He gas has been used in HDA's (head disk assy) in clean rooms by Servo writers for some time to improve accuracy at incredibly high track densities.

Can you imagine the turbulence of a jet flying at a height of 5 nanometers but only at a ground speed of 100kph above ultra-smooth glass? That's what happens inside modern HDDs.  Rugged yet sensitive to off-axis rotational acceleration.

Air causes turbulence which affects flying stability and to push the limits on servo accuracy some use Helium during the disk servo-writer process. But Seagate claims it also reduces the operating temperature by 5 degrees C.

Comment: I hate it when newbies to this technology vote-1 without comments.  This is just a marketing gimmick.

Comment: So are you answering yes it could be real printing, for a marketing sample, but there's no printing on functional units? Also air or He, isn't it really laminar-like flow between the head and disk to stabilize the height, not turbulent?

Comment: It's a gimmick for marketing only. flying height reduces with gas density which increases turbulence but gas density also reduces turbulence, but there are other factors.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Er, what? Given the expense of making hard disks air-tight and filling them with helium, it's very clearly not a marketing gimmick. (Nor are the enterprise customers who are buying these disks likely to be fooled by that kind of trickery.)

Comment: The photo is a gimmick not the helium. Real printing for show N tell.   The technical part of He is valid when it gets perfected but only gains 25% HDD density ( unless they squeeze more platters)  has hit a brick wall for gap resolution and track density, now shingle offset data tracks and helium aerodynamics are about the last increments in density.